# Android - How to show video duration like Instagram does?

Tags: android, instagram, android-videoview, duration

Instagram shows current duration while playing video in mm:ss format. It's not in the media controller bar, in a custom TextView which is on the corner of the video.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Not everyone knows what Instagram does. Some more detail would be nice

Comment: Not only does not everybody use Instagram, but Instagram's UI may change in the future. Stack Overflow questions need to be usable years from now. So, please edit your question, explain in detail what you are seeking, and provide a [mcve] of what you tried.